# Substring between two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple string like this:

```
image[2]
```

I want to get the number between `[]`, in this case have to return `2`.

What is a good regular expression to do this in JavaScript? I have tried  with `substring` but I want to apply a regular expression.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: @FelixKling +1 but sometimes this tag can be added by OP to tell *"I use jQuery so if your answer needs it, it's valid"*.

Comment: @FelixKling yes sorry but i'm using jQuery (like dystroy wrote) and is only an information, I didn't know if there is something in jQuery. Thanks for the correction +1

Comment: @dystroy: Totally agree. But that's not the case here :)

Comment: @FelixKling There *must* be a jQuery plugin for that.

Comment: @Alessandro: I understand and it can be confusing at the beginning what is jQuery and what is core JavaScript. But that's why it's even more important to point out when jQuery is irrelevant, IMOH. Basically, jQuery is irrelevant for anything that is not DOM manipulation or Ajax. String processing is core JavaScript.

Comment: Great explaination @FelixKling thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var num = parseInt(yourString.match(/\[(\d*)\]/)[1], 10);
```

This returns `2` as a number.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = "image[2]",
    r = /\[([^\]]*?)\]/;

console.log(a.match(r)); // ["[2]", "2"]
```

---

```
var num = +(a.match(r)[1]); // 2
```

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Please answer [at]user1394965 answer as the correct one that it answers the question and it was the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this: `\[(.*?)\]`